# Ruby C extension, how to recover from segmentation fault

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I've written a simple Ruby C extension.  A method expects the second parameter to be a string-ish VALUE.

```
VALUE method_foo(VALUE self, VALUE key) {

  puts(RSTRING(key)->ptr);

  return key;
}
```

Its very easy to cause a segmentation fault by passing an integer rather than a string.  How should I detect this and either prevent or recover in the C method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into calling `Check_Type (key, T_STRING)` (if you want an exception raised) or using `TYPE (key)` to check it manually (if you want to do something *other* than raise an exception).

Alternatively, you could simply state that `method_foo` expects a string and leave it up to the caller to handle. Your API is, after all, a contract between caller and callee and, if the caller breaks the rules, it's a perfectly valid response to crash.

I probably wouldn't do that since I prefer robust software but there's a school of thought that people shouldn't always necessarily be protected from their own foolishness. It only encourages them to stay foolish :-)

Comment: Nothing, thanks for the info.  I couldn't either of these listed on http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html

Comment: @Josh, it's there under "value as a pointer" - also have a look at http://clalance.blogspot.com.au/2011/01/writing-ruby-extensions-in-c-part-4.html

Comment: You are right about the API.  My main motivation for some "safety" is to make it harder to maliciously crash the program.  Although, this might be better left to a Ruby layer of cleansing user input.  (since the C functions are really about speed anyway).

Comment: I am blind sometimes :-)  The blogspot link addressed my exact problem:desired solution.

Answer (score 1):

StringValuePtr(value) and StringValueCStr(value) do the typechecking and return the string pointers. AFAIK, they are the accepted ways to extract a char* from a Ruby string in a C extension. Among things (as far as I remember when I looked into it), they both make sure that the returned value is not NULL (which can be in some cases), and StringValueCStr also makes sure that it is a 0-terminated string. Since Ruby strings use copy-on-write, a slice of a string might not be 0-terminated.